# Create fixed sized squares on large displays with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

Looking to create four fixed sized squares for large displays with fixed spacing between them, as shown in the picture below, with bootstrap and am finding it pretty tricky for some reason.

The problem I am currently experiencing when using solely bootstrap for creating the containers is that on displays that are roughly 1200-1400px large, the containers are sized okay, but the spacing is off and on very large displays 1400-1800+, the containers are too wide and the spacing too high as well.

My goal is to use bootstrap to create fixed sized divs with fixed spacing on large displays, i.e anything larger than 1200px.

This is what I tried:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" >
        <div class="service-container">
            <div class="service-nh">
                Square 1
            </div>
            Brown fox lazy jumped lorum ipsum foo bar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" >
        <div class="service-container">
            <div class="service-nh">
                Square 2
            </div>
            Brown fox lazy jumped lorum ipsum foo bar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" >
        <div class="service-container">
            <div class="service-nh">
                Square 3
            </div>
            Brown fox lazy jumped lorum ipsum foo bar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" >
        <div class="service-container">
            <div class="service-nh">
                Square 4
            </div>
            Brown fox lazy jumped lorum ipsum foo bar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Desired outcome on large displays (fixed squares w/ fixed spacing):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code works fine

```
    <style>
     @media(min-width :1200px){

    .box{
    width:500px; 
    border:1px solid #000;
     margin:auto;"

    }



}

</style>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" >
<div class="box">
    <div class="service-container">
        <div class="service-nh">
            Square 1
        </div>
        Brown fox lazy jumped lorum ipsum foo bar
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" >
<div class="box">
    <div class="service-container">
        <div class="service-nh">
            Square 2
        </div>
        Brown fox lazy jumped lorum ipsum foo bar
    </div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" >
<div class="box">
    <div class="service-container">
        <div class="service-nh">
            Square 3
        </div>
        Brown fox lazy jumped lorum ipsum foo bar
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" >
<div class="box">
    <div class="service-container">
        <div class="service-nh">
            Square 4
        </div>
        Brown fox lazy jumped lorum ipsum foo bar
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not work for me, the spacing is off with the margin set to auto. The perceived spacing between the boxes is 250-350px on large displays. Setting the margin to anything other than auto, did not work for me either. I appreciate it though.